# System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid, when using Directory.EnumerateDirectories

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a windowservice to import stuff to my system. Sometimes I get a "System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid". Does anyone know why this exception occurs?

Below you can see the code thats triggers the exception:

```
 foreach (string directoryPath in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
 {
            // Import logic
 }
```

My guess is that the underlying collection is changed during the execution, but I'm not sure of it.

Here is the stacktrace by the way:

System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()

Comment: what's in "            // Import logic " ?

Comment: Have you looked at this post.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224833/executing-a-process-on-separate-thread-results-in-system-io-error-winioerror

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to write to either the console or another output stream that the service does not have a valid Win32 handle for.

Comment: Which methods throws the exception? Could be a concurrency issue if the folder structure changes while enumerating.

Comment: in the foreach loop I'm reading a xmlfile, transforms it and stores it in another location.

Comment: I am getting the same thing for Directory.GetFiles(filePath, searchPattern)