# How to fix random FileSystemEnumerableIterator.MoveNext Error. The handle is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I just started randomly getting the error on a program that has been running for years. all this program does is look at a set of directories and delete files based on their last write time.
Here is the error and stack trace.

> Error: The handle is invalid.
>
> Stack Trace: at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
> maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
> at DirectoryCleaner.Program.GetNewFiles()

Here is the code

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
foreach (FileSystemInfo file in di.EnumerateFileSystemInfos(variablePattern == true ? "*" : SearchPattern, searchSubDirectories == true ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{ 
creates queue of records to delete. I removed the logic as it is rather long... 
}
```

I have spent several hours searching. I found
[System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid, when using Directory.EnumerateDirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847626/system-io-ioexception-the-handle-is-invalid-when-using-directory-enumeratedire) but it does not have an answer.

The stack trace shows that it is in the MoveNext method which I do not directly call. I assume the foreach loop calls it. How can I correct what is causing this?

Comment: Is it possible that anything is deleting a file while it is being enumerated?

Comment: Not that I can find. It is possible a new file was added to the directory.  Does EnumerateDirectories  in a foreach check for new files each time it loops? I thought it grabbed what was in the directory at the time of the call and then loop through that count.

Comment: If you recursively search subdirectories, a "search stack" is created at least in the .NET Framework 4.8 code, but it's not clear to me at first glance whether that could cause an invalid handle to be created https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directoryinfo.cs,d215b374681bf5ab You might approach this by catching the exception, logging when it happens (look for patterns) and retry the code when you receive the exception (be sure you cannot end up in an infinite loop... maybe retry up to N times).

Comment: Thanks, I will check the logs and see if I can find a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because the various file/directory `EnumerateX` methods are effectively wrappers around the native Win32 `FindFirstFile` function, and [as per its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew):

> If the function fails or fails to locate files from the search string in the `lpFileName` parameter, **the return value is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`** and the contents of `lpFindFileData` are indeterminate. To get extended error information, call the `GetLastError` function.

If we look at the [relevant portion of the Framework Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/__error.cs,187), we see that any error not handled explicitly is surfaced as an `IOException`. This would include `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

In other words, *this is an expected potential exception* while calling an `EnumerateX` method and your code should handle it correctly by catching the generic `IOException`. The docs for the various `EnumerateX` methods fail to call this out, which IMO is an omission, and as such I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/6752) to get that fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will add the needed logic to handle these exceptions as I ready catch the error.